# How to override save method to change data in Django?

Tags: django

Model:

```
ATTN_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('N', 'Entry'),
    ('X', 'Exit'),
    ('L', 'Leave'),
)


class Attn(Timestamp):
    emp_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=10
    )
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField(
        default=time(00, 00)
    )
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=ATTN_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default='N'
    )

    @property
    def late(self):
        return type == 'N' and self.time > LATE_LIMIT

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            Attn.objects.get(emp_id=self.emp_id, date=self.date, type='N')
        except Attn.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        else:
            try:
                exit = Attn.objects.get(emp_id=self.emp_id, date=self.date, type='X')
            except Attn.DoesNotExist:
                self.type = 'X'
            else:
                exit.delete()
        super(Attn, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('emp_id', 'date', 'type')
```

I will create objects thrice. The first time is simple. The type will be `N`. The second time I want the save method to check if type `N` already exists, if it does, then change the type to 'X' and save second object. Third time, I want it to check for `N` and then for `X`. But this time it will find `X` and will delete the existing entry for `X` before saving the new entry with type `X`.

For some reason, the code seems to get stuck at the `unique_together` and doesn't let me save data from the admin panel. Should I try and catch the `Integrityerror` for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try editing the save method like this,

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        Attn.objects.get(emp_id=self.emp_id, date=self.date, type='N')
        try:
            exit = Attn.objects.get(emp_id=self.emp_id, date=self.date, type=='X')
            exit.delete()                
        except Attn.DoesNotExist:
            self.type = 'X'
        else:
            self.type = 'X'
    except Attn.DoesNotExist:
        self.type = 'N'

    return super(Attn, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Remove the unique_together constraint, its not needed now, you are explicitly overriding the save method and restricting the app to save objects with the conditions above..

**EDIT**

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#unique-together),

> The ValidationError raised during model validation when the constraint is violated has the unique_together error code.

That means, if the unique_together constraint is violated then, the ValidationError is raised in the model validation itself. Django never even try to reach near the save method, if the constraint is failed. Thus, django-admin raises error before committing the object to the database.

Comment: Nope. Same error. It seems django admin is blocking me for saving another entry with type `N` because of the `unique_together`.

Comment: remove the unique_together constraint, its not needed now, you are explicitly overriding the save method and restricting the app to save objects with the conditions above... remove the constraint, it should work..

Comment: Can you please explain why I cannot keep it? Why is it triggering before the save method is complete?

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Also, the main problem was the `unique_together` constraint. The save method actually works exactly how I want in my code.